# `seq` on partially applied functions

Tags: haskell, seq

Lets say I have the following:

```
f :: a -> b -> c
g :: b -> c
g = f 10
```

Now lets say `f` is actually:

```
f x y = f1 x + y
```

Would:

```
g `seq` ...
```

actually evaluate `f1 10`, so later when running

```
g 9
```

it's actually just a simple addition?

If not, is there a way to "evaluate" parts of a partially applied function?

I'm looking for a generic solution, one that doesn't depend on knowing how `f` and `g` work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`seq` is shallow:

```
Prelude> let f1 = undefined
Prelude> let f = \x -> \y -> f1 x + y
Prelude> let g = f 10
Prelude> g `seq` 1
1
Prelude> g 9
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
Prelude>
```

I'd take a look at `Control.DeepSeq`: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/deepseq/1.2.0.1/doc/html/Control-DeepSeq.html

Comment: I doesn't look like I can apply `deepseq` to functions.

Comment: No, it looks like it only applies to data structures that take DeepSeq into account.  Not a solution to your problem as stated.

Answer (score 9):

No, it will not, because in general, the choice of right hand side for `f` might depend on `y`. If you want to share the result of `f1 x` between calls to `g`, you would have to write `f` like this:

```
f x = let z = f1 x in \y -> z + y
```

Of course, due to laziness this will not evaluate `f1 x` until the first time `g` is called. To have `` g `seq` ... `` force evaluation of `f1 x`, you would have to write:

```
f x = let z = f1 x in z `seq` (\y -> z + y)
```